# A mathematical brain teaser in probability field

Tags: probability, dynamic-programming

That is a brain teaser but it is also a mathematical problem in probability field.

One day, a man have been trapped into a building which has 18 floors. Now, he want to leave the building but there is a guard.

**Assumptions:**

1. if the man bribes the guard by 10 thousand dollors, he will down 1 stair (with probability 1).
2. If he invites the guard to dinner spending 20 thousand dollors, he will down 3 stairs with 80% probability while he will in vain with 20% probablity.
3. If he bribes the guard's wife by a 30 thousand cosmetic, he will down a half of stairs with 50% probability(e.g., 12 floor will down to 6 floor, 9 floor will down to 5 floor. Odd floor will down to $(n+1)/2$). Also, he will in vain with 50% probability.

**The problem is:** if the man has 150 thousand dollors, how does him spend money will has a highest probability to leave the building(Say, the floor number is less or equal to 0)?

This is similar to a programing problem but has probability. So I wonder if there some mathematical theory about it and how to solve the problem?

Comment: This problem is missing a lot of information.  Does the man know what floor he is on?  Does he know if the guard is below him?  How is the guard's starting location determined?  Presumably if the man and the guard are on the same floor, the man loses. Does the guard disappear if the guard goes below $0$, in which case just playing move 1 wins with a reasonable probability and any other has to compete with that?  -1 for badly stating the problem.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thank you for your comments. Maybe I lose some details. Obviously, the man know where he is all the time. The function of the guard is determine where the trapped man can he go. Thus guard's position is trivial. You can consider that the guard at the door of the building.

Comment: If I know the guard is at the door, I take option 1, send him down a floor to the basement and walk out of the building.  If I am on floor 15 or lower and know the guard is below me, I can succeed certainly by using option 1 enough.  The only problem comes if I don't know where I am (I don't think it is obvious that I do) or the guard might be very high up.

Comment: But you only have 150 thousand dollars then you can only go to floor 3 if you choose option 1. Maybe I should point out that initially the trapped man is at 18th floor.

Comment: That is correct, which is why I said I chose option 1 if I start at 15 or lower.  If the guard might be higher, option 2, with an expectation of 1.2 floors/1000 dollars is attractive.  Do I get to know the result of each trial?  If I do option 2 twice and it works both times, I am guaranteed a win using 1 after that.

Comment: As the other two answers, maybe there is no closed form solution of this problem. So the trail may be gotten by Monte Carlo or other simulation methods.

Answer (score 3):

## Dynamic programming approach

Let $p_{i,j} = \{\text{probability of escaping given that the guard is in floor $i$ and I have $j$ dollars}\}$. You want to compute $p_{18,150}$. It is easy to see that $p_{0,j} = 1$ and $p(i, 0) = 0$ for any $i>0$, $j\geq 0$. There is a recurrence relation (you need to fill the dots with the 3rd case)

$p_{i, j} = \max{\{p_{i-1,j-10},\quad 0.8 p_{i-3, j-20} + 0.2 p_{i, j-20},\quad \cdots\}}$

This recurrence allows you to compute the term you need in $O(I*J)$ (I = maximum i, J = maximum j) if you store the terms you already computed in a table.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! And I think this is the one I need. BTW, in your formula, $p_{i,j}=\max\dots$, what is the meaning of $p_{i-1,j-10}0.8p_{i-3,j-20}$? Is there lose an add operator?

Comment: There is a comma in the middle. The $\max$ means to choose the better option between the 3 available: $p_{i-1,j-10}$ represents the first one. You go down with probability 1 and you loose 10$. The second options is a sum of 2 term weighted by the probability of each event happening.

Comment: OK, Thank you, I get it!

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you need to know the expected payoff for each possible strategy that the trapped man can utilize.  In this case, an expected payoff greater than zero means that he has a probability greater than zero of making it out of the building before running out of money.

A possible strategy might be something like, first bribe the wife in the hope that he will get down half of the floors, i.e., from floor 18 to floor 9, then bribe the guard 3 times and if necessary, pay for any remaining floors.

A given strategy leads to a set of sequences of choices, depending upon the outcome of the random elements of the problem.  So, if everything goes according to plan, the strategy I outlined would lead to the expenditure of $\$30k + 3 * \$20k = \$90k$.  However, the probability of everything going as well as possible is only $0.5 * (0.8)^3 = 0.256$.

I see that you linked to dynamic programming.  Dynamic programming is a way of keeping track of all the possible paths through the graph of possibilities.  Instead of calculating a separate cost and probability for each possible sequence of events, the partial probabilities and partial costs of the various paths are preserved in a table so that they don't have to be recomputed.  It also helps to reduce the number of computations because one can see that cells that are far from the optimal path can't be reached without going through suboptimal cells.

That's the best I can do at this point.  I don't think there is a neat, closed form solution to your problem.  Your best bet is to use a dynamic programming approach to reduce the amount of work required to compute an answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It seems a complex conditional probability problem as you said 'A given strategy leads to a set of sequences of choices, depending upon the outcome of the random elements of the problem.'. I also think there is no closed form answer now but Monte Carlo simulation maybe helpful to figure it out.

Comment: Also, I wonder are there some algorithm in dynamic programming for the probatilistic problem like this?

Comment: I think you are referring to this idea, though I'm not quite sure how to apply it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman_equation#The_Bellman_equation_in_a_stochastic_problem

Comment: @TomHallward, Thank you for your link, I think there a little difference between the two problems. In the Bellman equation, an exception function will be maximized. But in this problem, we only need to maximize the probability.